# PC turns on a few minutes after I put it on sleep, then goes to sleep again

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I always put my computer to sleep at night and I started having the problem in the title about a week ago.

I put the computer to sleep and after 5-15 minutes it turns back on, stays on for a few minutes, then goes back to sleep.

How can I find out the reason or fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was because of an AMD driver that added a new service to the system (AdaptiveSleepService).

I've stopped the service and it seems to be working.

Found the fix [here](https://theohbrothers.com/solve-windows-10-waking-for-brief-moment-and-going-back-to-sleephibernation/).

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/31/find-pc-wakes-stop/) explains some of the methods to find devices or utilities that are responsible.
You shouldn't need more than a PowerShell.